# How to resolve error: Used by 'Kendo.MVC' matches identity System.Web.MVC. You may need to supply runtime policy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

[image]

I am getting error message as shown in the screenshot below. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the package manager and enter following

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.0 -whatif
```

the runtime policy issue must be fixed after this.

Comment: Will check that.

Comment: You can also mark it as answer, so other people can benefit from this answer.